# Error while running a DAG task from Airflow CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, boto3, airflow-2.x

```
ERROR - Unable to retrieve connection from secrets backend (MetastoreBackend). Checking subsequent secrets backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 424, in get_connection_from_secrets
    conn = secrets_backend.get_connection(conn_id=conn_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    with create_session() as session:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 33, in create_session
    raise RuntimeError("Session must be set before!")
RuntimeError: Session must be set before!

[2023-08-28T13:38:49.329+0000] {base_aws.py:566} WARNING - Unable to find AWS Connection ID 'airflow-logs-tst', switching to empty.

[2023-08-28T13:38:49.330+0000] {base_aws.py:160} INFO - No connection ID provided. Fallback on boto3 credential strategy (region_name='\x1b[01mNone\x1b[22m').
```

Versions of packages used:
Airflow - `2.6.0`
SqlAlchemy - `1.4.49`
Psycopg2-binary - `2.9,7`

Note: I'm not using any of the connection information from the airflow metadata backend DB, nor am I using any third party secrets manager like AWS. Also I am using a IAM account for authentication.